# EU Employer demands birth certificate - Why?

Tags: employer, identity-theft, birth-certificate

My brother is Irish, he starts a job as manager of a bar in France. He provided his Irish Passport for id, and the employer wants an original birth certificate.

My understanding is birth certificate, without being notarised, are not recognised outside there country of issue. In addition, they are not official documents for id (since they lack a photo). However, my understanding is passports are officially recognised internationally as id. Two other brothers live in Germany and Spain, both residents of those countries, both obtained their residency without any need for birth certificates (just passports).

Birth certificates can be used as part of identity theft so alarm bells ring for me.

Is there any reason why an employer might demand a birth certificate? Is there any reason why an Irish passport would not suffice?

Answer (score 6):

This is weird. Within the EU, a passport is proof of identity, and it is also proof that you are allowed to take a job in the EU. There is nothing that a birth certificate would add to this.

Either the bar manager is badly misinformed, or he doesn't want to give your brother a job, and will come up with something even more ridiculous if he gets the birth certificate.

Comment: The request for the birth cert came after he arrived, before his first work day which led me to think they might be reconsidering their offer.  He is 51, looks a little older which may be not to their liking. They were keen when talking over the phone, especially so since he previously had a London Pub of the Year award. He is still there - They not made clear why they need the birth cert despite he asking.